# How to use IEEE Editorial in specific cases

Tags: ieee-style

I hope this is the right place to ask this. If not, I'm thankful for any tips on where to ask this questions - e.g. special forums or even support as apa provides it for the apa-style.

- Is there a manual for the german version of IEEE (this version is
  called IEEE Editorial (German))? I know there is one for the english
  version.
- When emphasizing words, should you use "" or italics?
- If one       mentions the title of an article as a quote, do you need
  to cite it?
- I saw that IEEE usually is made for articles. Can I still use it for
  my masters thesis?

Thank you.

Comment: Try https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/?lang=de  For emphasis, use \emph{...}.  The formatting requirements for a thesis and for IEEE publication will probably not match.

Comment: Which citation style or guideline would you recommend for a thesis? Or let's say, is there even a citation style that is also "made for" theses? Most of them are only working with articles in the first place if one is exact.

Comment: Ask your major professor about citation styles.  I barely know that such things exist.

Comment: So you would say it mostly is up to preference how one emphasizes words e.g.? It's just that I was used to APA7 which has clear rules for this. It seems to be less dramatic in physics-related citations so this is good to know. Thank you!

Comment: Normally \emph italicizes, unless one is already using italics.  OTOH, if a publisher wanted some;thing different, they could always redefine \emph accordingly.